# Photoshop Script Renaming Files On Mac Not Working

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop-script

I need to rename files using Photoshop Script and the code works fine on Windows but doesn't work on Macintosh. The code runs without error but the files name stays the same on Mac OS. It changes the file name on Windows.

Hostscript Code:

```
function RenameTest(){
  var fpath = Folder.myDocuments + '/test.rtf'; 
  var nfile = File(fpath); 
  var nfile_newname = Folder.myDocuments + '/test.ini'; 
  nfile.rename(nfile_newname);
}
```

Main.js Code:

```
csInterface.evalScript('RenameTest()');
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: Yes. Thanks much appreciated. nfile_newname must be just the file name and nfile = new File(fpath); Weird that it works just like that on windows.

Comment: What's the error that photoshop shows? Does `Folder.myDocuments` exist on mac?

Comment: The code runs without any errors. I fixed it, so it works now.

Comment: Would you like to answer or remove this question? We'd prefer it if you could answer the question and share the solution you found

Comment: @AB700 It may seem pointless now, but if you answer you own question you might be able to help someone with a similar issue in the future.

Comment: Ok thanks, I answered my question. I thought it just a simple thing but you are right. Someone else might need the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if anyone needs it.

This code works in Windows but not on Mac:

```
function RenameTest(){
  var fpath = Folder.myDocuments + '/test.rtf'; 
  var nfile = File(fpath); 
  var nfile_newname = Folder.myDocuments + '/test.ini'; 
  nfile.rename(nfile_newname);
}
```

This works on both Windows and Mac:

```
function RenameTest(){
  var fpath = Folder.myDocuments + '/test.rtf'; 
  var nfile = File(fpath); 
  var nfile_newname = 'test.ini'; 
  nfile.rename(nfile_newname);
}
```

The nfile.rename must only be the file name and extension. Don't add the path.